# Can I pre-cook Tri Tip and finish it later?

Tags: food-safety, meat, temperature, beef, smoking

I like to smoke tri tip to an internal temp of 100F, then sear it on the grill to an internal temp of 130F. Could I take the meat out of the smoker at 100F, cool it down with ice to 60F, store it in the fridge and sear it to 130F the next day. I'm worried about botulism.

Comment: See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/76208/can-i-finish-cooking-a-pork-roast-next-day-after-partially-cooking-it/112370

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I finish cooking a pork roast next day after partially cooking it](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/76208/can-i-finish-cooking-a-pork-roast-next-day-after-partially-cooking-it)

Comment: botulism is a risk in canned or fermented foods, not really meat the way you're cooking. Check https://www.cdc.gov/botulism/prevention.html

Comment: I'd say your biggest risk is E.Coli, and that's only if you don't give it a good sear--when you say "sear to 130", if you mean "until the interior is 130", then the outside should have some char and be well over 160, that's probably OK.